# How does the "Target framework" affect the way the machine.config and GAC are used with Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, target-framework

I'm trying to understand how a project's Target framework is being used and how it affects loading assemblies. Here is the issue.

In Visual Studio 2015 Community, my default Target framework is .NET 4.6.1. When left at this setting, I used NuGet to install Npgsql 3.0.7 as the driver to the local backend PostgreSQL database. When using

> DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName)

VS reported that the Provider could not be found.  (This after Npgsql 3.0.7 was installed in machine.config and the GAC.)

In researching this ([DbProviderFactories Demystified](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/netfx/2010/12/dbproviderfactories-demystified)), the statement is made that

> DbProviderFactories simply invokes Type.GetType to load Assembly and
>   create an instance of the Type.

Which led me to researching Npgsql 3.0.7 a little more. When NuGet installed the assembly, it placed it at

> C:...\packages\Npgsql.3.0.7\lib\net45\Npgsql.dll

Taking the "net45" as being .NET 4.5, I changed the Target framework of the project to .NET 4.5.2. Upon rebuilding, all runs well without warning or errors.

So how does the "Target framework" affect the way the machine.config and GAC are used?

Thanks for any explanation (or reference).

Note: There was never any warning in Solution Explorer that the Npgsql assembly is incompatible with .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation is separate from runtime execution. When you choose a target framework, Visual Studio/MSBuild checks the reference assemblies in the target profile to compile the project.

At runtime, first Windows will decide which .NET Framework installed should be used. Then it would be that version of .NET Framework to decide how to run the program with its GAC and machine.config (and other bits).

The NuGet version net45 means .NET Framework 4.5 and above.